# Bactrack5 + VMWare + GNOME Fail

Tags: gnome, vmware, backtrack

When I attempt to run any of the preinstalled GUI apps with `startx` it fails to run and terminates with the output

`failed to load module "vmwgfx" (module does not exist, 0)"`

Followed by `...xterm...` several times. Sorry I do not have the full output handy to copy and paste here.

Apparently the GNOME GUI isn't going to run out-of-the-box here, and a VMWare tools installation is needed. So as I'm waiting on the next image to download, in a lengthy process of trial and error, installation, and VMWare tools patches,**can someone suggest which [configuration](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/downloads/) is most likely to succeed in running `gedit` with the least amount of hassle?**

I have a Windows 7 64-bit host running Backtrack 5 RX with VMWare Workstation 9. 
Is there any reason one of either GNOME or KDE might be more compatible than the other with a VMWare + Backtrack?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this thread, titled: [[Linux guests] vmwgfx Testing](http://communities.vmware.com/thread/270716?start=15&tstart=0), from the VMWare Community site. There are somethings to try in that thread, but it looks like VMWare is providing a new driver, vmwgfx, in Workstation 9 that you're distro is getting tripped up on.

Given your error I would assume that Backtrack 5 doesn't include this particular driver.

Typically with the virtualization products like VMWare and Virtualbox there are "extensions" that you have to either install via the virtualization products GUIs or manually mount some CD/ISO inside the guests to get these sorts of drivers/modules installed.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/264900/64-bit-or-32-bit-guest-for-a-64-bit-host-vmware

Comment: I don't understand why you sent this link, could you elaborate please? Thanks.